# Are you running Win 7 on a Intel Pentium 4 Motherboard

Tags: windows-7

Is anyone running Win 7 on an Intel P4 MB with the monitor attached to the MB connector ?  If so, what VGA driver are you using? Does Win7 allow 800x600 and higher screen resolutions ?

---

Attempting to upgrade to Win7 from XP Pro screen coloration problems at 800x600 - the only allowed resolution

No issues under XP Pro SP3, on a different HDD and the Monitor ( HP vx74 ) performed as expected.

A screen capture is shown at n2006b.com/Res

- Intel D845GERG2L a 2003 MB A97835-106
- Onboard Video Chipset: Intel Extreme Graphics
- Monitor HP vx74 using Microsoft Driver 6.1.7600.16385 which Win7 says is up to date

Comment: your question currently looks very opinion based. Please specify your issue and try to reword it.

Comment: we need more details, exact HW configuration/model..

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I agree there are problems with this question, but I would say answers to it (as asked) should be reasonably objective. There isn't a lot of oppinion in answering with the name of your driver. Op, there isn't a universal answer to this question unless you specify a specific Motherboard version. P4 chips did not have GPU components the way most modern CPUs do, so the integrated graphics card is wholly on teh motherboard. you will find some AMD, some Nvidia, and others, in varying makes and models. Start with your motherboar mode, find its specs online, and look at the vid specs.

Comment: Issue :  Attempting to upgrade to Win7 from XP Pro 
           screen  coloration  problems at 800x600 -only allowed resolution
           
           No issues under XP Pro SP3, on a different HDD
             and the Monitor ( HP vx74 )  performed as expected. 
A screen capture is shown at  http://n2006b.com/Res/

Intel D845GERG2L    a 2003 MB  A97835-106

Intel Desktop Board D845GERG2L -

 Onboard Video Chipset:  Intel Extreme Graphics

Monitor  HP vx74 using
    Microsoft Driver 6.1.7600.16385  which Win7 says is up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that Intel never provided WDDM 1.1 (Win 7) drivers for old hardware like your 845G chipset's GPU (i.e., Intel Extreme Graphics).

You may try to download & extract the following drivers, go to the device manager and action menu 'Add legacy hardware', then manually point to the .inf file of the intel driver. 
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/8344

Otherwise, you will have trouble running it, and getting a cheap/not too old AGP GPU  (since you have not PCIe port on your MB) may help.

Comment: Well, I followed your instructions and the 82845G is now running and the 1024x768 is working perfectly.  Thanks so much for your excellent assistance.  Next I think I'll add a ATI Rage PCI card and 2nd Monitor

Comment: Mark the answer as "correct" so the community knows that the trick works :)